# News / Tag Aggregation Packages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, twitter

In an attempt to avoid writing my own aggregator for an existent Ruby on Rails app and WordPress blog, I'd like to be able to aggregate various chatter going on in various mediums at one central page based on particular keywords, etc.

This aggregator can live either on the blog or within the Rails app, it doesn't matter.

For example, let's say I want to continually poll Google News, Twitter, public Facebook, and perhaps others, for "chocolate chip cookies."  Is there a package that already facilitates this or am I in a "roll it yourself" situation?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is using HTTParty to deal with the APIs those services expose...